# How to remove values from drop-down if value deleted from validation list

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have 2 sheets in same workbook, one is data sheet and 2nd sheet contains the data validation values. I am facing problem while removing value from a cell (in data sheet) (which contains data validation). **The issue is when I try to remove the value from validation list, the same value didn't remove from the cell.** (see screen shot)
"e.g. if I want to remove volunteer name from the validation list, the value didn't delete from cell in data sheet (cell highlighted in screenshot)."

I have written a vba code to add multiple values in same cell separated by commas. I would appreciate if someone help me to solve this issue.
My VBA code is below:

```
    Option Explicit
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngDV As Range
    Dim oldVal As String
    Dim newVal As String
    Dim lUsed As Long
    If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
    On Error GoTo exitHandler

    If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler

    If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then
    'do nothing
    Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    newVal = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    oldVal = Target.Value
    Target.Value = newVal
    If Target.Column = 3 Or Target.Column = 4 Or Target.Column = 5 Or Target.Column = 6 Or 
    Target.Column = 7 Or Target.Column = 8 _
                       Or Target.Column = 9 Or Target.Column = 11 Then
                    
    If oldVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
      If newVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
        lUsed = InStr(1, oldVal, newVal)
        If lUsed > 0 Then
            If Right(oldVal, Len(newVal)) = newVal Then
                Target.Value = Left(oldVal, Len(oldVal) - Len(newVal) - 2)
            Else
                Target.Value = Replace(oldVal, newVal & ", ", "")
            End If
        Else
            Target.Value = oldVal _
              & ", " & newVal
        End If
        
        End If
        End If
        End If
        End If

        exitHandler:
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        End Sub
```

You can find the worksheet from the link below: (**show1** Sheet is data sheet and **Validation Fields** contains the drop-down values)

[Excel Sheet](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ljl8sol36imf3mw/Routine%20Assessment%20Spreadsheet%20%2812%29.xlsm?dl=0)

Thanks

[image: sheet where drop-down value inserted]

[image: data validation list]

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const SEP As String = ","
    Dim c As Range, NewValue As String, OldValue As String, arr, v, lst, removed As Boolean

    On Error GoTo Exitsub

    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub '<< only handling single-cell changes

    Select Case Target.Column
        Case 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11
            Set c = Target
        Case Else: Exit Sub
    End Select
    
    If Len(c.Value) > 0 And Not c.Validation Is Nothing Then

        Application.EnableEvents = False
        NewValue = c.Value
        Application.Undo
        OldValue = c.Value

        If OldValue = "" Then
            c.Value = NewValue
        Else
            arr = Split(OldValue, SEP)
            'loop over previous list, removing newvalue if found
            For Each v In arr
                If Trim(CStr(v)) = NewValue Then
                    removed = True
                Else
                    lst = lst & IIf(lst = "", "", SEP) & v
                End If
            Next v
            'add the new value if we didn't just remove it
            If Not removed Then lst = lst & IIf(lst = "", "", SEP) & NewValue
            c.Value = lst
        End If
    End If    'has validation and non-empty
    
Exitsub:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Well it didn't work and facing same error.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/q6hd36tn0i2ajh9/main.PNG?dl=0

Comment: Use the drop-down and select Lisa to remove that name. First time you select it adds the name: if you select the same name again it will remove it.  You can't have a list-based validation *and* manually edit the list in the cell...

Comment: In case if the value removed from the validation list. It can't remove from the Show sheet because the value have been deleted from the drop-down so can't remove it by select it again. Is there any solution of this issue?

Comment: If you remove a value from a list, you'd need to review all of the cells which have a list validation, and check that whatever value(s) have been selected are still in the list.  You could trigger that with a button or with a Change event on the Validation Fields sheet.  You can check each cell against its list source using something like : https://exceloffthegrid.com/loop-through-each-item-in-a-data-validation-list-with-vba/

Comment: Thank you for your response and I got your point and implemented in the code and get the desire results thank you so much for your help.